# Find the value of $\sec x$ using knowing that $9\sin x + 40\cos x = 41$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find the value of $\sec x$ using equation $9\sin x + 40\cos x = 41$.

I have tried to solve but I failed.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to math.SE! What did you try to solve it? Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: Hint: Use $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ to transform the problem into a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

$a \sin x +b\cos x=c$

*divide by $\cos x$*

$a\tan x+b=\frac{c}{\cos x}$

*take b to the other side,then square both sides*

$a^2\tan ^2x=\frac{c^2}{\cos^2 x}-\frac{cb}{\cos x}+b^2$

*use the identity*

$\tan^2x+1=\sec ^2x$

$0=(c^2-a^2)\sec^2x-bc\sec x+b^2-a^2$

use quadratic formular

$\sec x=\frac{bc\pm \sqrt{b^2c^2-4(c^2-a^2)(b^2-a^2)}}{2(c^2-a^2)}$

Comment: Could it be that $a^2\tan ^2x=\frac{c^2}{\cos^2 x}-\frac{2cb}{\cos x}+b^2$.

Answer (score 4):

I find it coincidental that $41^2-40^2=(41-40)(41+40)=9^2$.  Let's try dividing both sides by 41.

$$\frac9{41}\sin x+\frac{40}{41}\cos x=1$$
$$\sin(x+\cos^{-1}\frac9{41})=1$$
$$x+\cos^{-1}\frac9{41}=\frac\pi2$$
$$\cos x=\cos(\frac\pi2-\cos^{-1}\frac9{41})=\sin(\cos^{-1}\frac9{41})$$
$$\cos x=\frac{40}{41},\sec x=\frac{41}{40}$$

Comment: How did you get the 3rd line ($\sin(x+\cos^{-1}\frac9{41}$)) ?

Comment: @derivative Since $9^2+40^2=41^2,(\frac{9}{41})^2+(\frac{40}{41})^2=1$.  So it's basically $\cos a\sin x+\sin a\cos x=\sin(x+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sec x = a.\;$ Then 
$$\cos x = \frac{1}{a},\quad \sin x = \sqrt{1 -\frac{1}{a^2}}.$$ Now substitute and square
$$\frac{81(a^2-1)}{a^2}= \left(41-\frac{40}{a}\right)^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow 81(a^2-1)= \left(41-\frac{40}{a}\right)^2a^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow 1600 a^2- 3280 a +1681 = (40a - 41)^2 = 0$$
Now you read off the solution $a = \sec x = \frac{41}{40} = 1.025$

Answer (score 0):

Avoid squaring whenever possible as it immediately  introduces extraneous root(s)

Use [Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\dfrac x2$

Now $\displaystyle\sec2A=\frac1{\cos2A},\cos2A=\frac{1-\tan^2A}{1+\tan^2A}$

Comment: @user175293, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that $9, 40, 41$ is a Pythagorean triple, that is, 
$9^2 + 40^2 = 41^2,$ 
consider the right triangle with legs $9$ and $40$ and hypotenuse $41.$

Let $\theta$ be the angle opposite the leg of length $9$ in that triangle.
Then $\sin \theta = \frac{9}{41}$ and $\cos \theta = \frac{9}{41}.$
Moreover,
$$ 9 \sin \theta + 40 \cos \theta
 = 9 \left(\frac{9}{41}\right) + 40 \left(\frac{40}{41}\right)
 = \frac{9^2 + 40^2}{41} = 41.
$$
Therefore $x = \theta$ solves the desired equation, and
$$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos \theta} = \frac{41}{40}.$$